# PlayFramework 2.4 Scala ActionRefiner with parameter from url usage

Tags: scala, playframework

I've made ActionRefiner to read language of current request from parameter in url:

```
class LangRequest[A](val lang: Lang, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

  def LangAction(lang: String) = new ActionRefiner[Request, LangRequest] {
    def refine[A](input: Request[A]) = Future.successful {
      val availLangs: List[String] = Play.current.configuration.getStringList("play.i18n.langs").get.toList
      if (!availLangs.contains(lang))
        Left {
          input.acceptLanguages.head match {
            case Lang(value, _) if availLangs.contains(value) => Redirect(controllers.routes.Application.index(value))
            case _ => Redirect(controllers.routes.Application.index(availLangs.head))
          }
        }
      else Right {
        new LangRequest(Lang(lang), input)
      }
    }
  }
```

and try to use it in action like this:

```
  def login(lng: String) =  LangAction(lng) { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
      Ok("Ok")
    }
```

And I've got

> "play.api.mvc.ActionRefiner[play.api.mvc.Request,controllers.actionbuilders.LangRequest]
>   does not take parameters"

error at compilation time. How can I use this ActionRefiner? In PlayFramework documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaActionsComposition they show ActionRefiner usages with Filter, Transformer like this:

```
(UserAction andThen ItemAction(itemId) andThen PermissionCheckAction)
```

and this does work. But how to use one ActionRefiner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry; this is pretty old, but I am facing a similar problem and wanted to post the solution so others could find it. I suspect it is because the first item in the chain of actions should be an ActionBuilder, in addition to whatever else. ActionTransformer is not a subtype of ActionBuilder, though it can be an argument to ActionBuilder#andThen.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, the `ActionBuilder` has to be the first element in the chain based on https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaActionsComposition#Putting-it-all-together

On the other hand, there are scenarios where we need to pass arguments to the `ActionRefiner` due to interactions with the database (e.g. retrieve products using id). At this point, we need to `@Inject` dependencies like services to get access to DB and the function is a partial solution. So, we can wrap the function in class to inject the dependencies and also inherent from `ActionBuilder` due to we can have only one element in the chain and we need to start with an `ActionBuilder`.

```scala
class UserActionBuilder @Inject()(
  val defaultBodyParsers: BodyParsers.Default,
  userService: UserService
)(implicit val ec: ExecutionContext) {

  def refine(userEmail: String): ActionRefiner[Request, UserRequest] with ActionBuilder[UserRequest, AnyContent] =
    new ActionRefiner[Request, UserRequest] with ActionBuilder[UserRequest, AnyContent] {

      def executionContext: ExecutionContext = ec

      override def refine[A](request: Request[A]): Future[Either[Result, UserRequest[A]]] = {

        userService.retrieveUserByEmail(userEmail)
          .map {
            case Some(user) if user.isActive => Right(UserRequest(user, request))
            case _ => Left(Results.Forbidden("User is inactive"))
          }
          .recover { case ex: Throwable =>
            Left(Results.InternalServerError(ex.getMessage))
          }
      }

      override def parser: BodyParser[AnyContent] = defaultBodyParsers
    }
}

case class UserRequest[A](user: User, request: Request[A])
  extends WrappedRequest[A](request)
```

And then

```scala
class UserController @Inject()(
  arguments...,
  userAction: UserActionBuilder
)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) {

  def updateUserPurchase(emailUser: String): Action[UserPurchaseRequest] = {
    userAction.refine(emailUser)).async(apiParser.parserOf[UserPurchaseRequest]) { implicit request =>
      ...
      doUpdate(request.body, request.user)
      ...
    }
  }
}
```